# error using rspec for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am using rspec for testing devise authentication. Following is my code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

describe "user registration" do
it "allows new users to register with an email address and password" do
get "/users/sign_up"

fill_in "Email",                 :with => "abc@example.com"
fill_in "Password",              :with => "abc123"
fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => "abc123"

 click_button "Sign up"

   response.should have_content("Welcome! You have signed up successfully.")
  end
 end
end
```

I am getting the following error.

"NoMethodError:undefined method `get' for #"

Answer (score 2):

You are using controller methods and integration test methods (Capybara) in a Model spec. It will not work.

A model spec (UNIT test) will contain things like:

1. Test your validators/relationships
2. Test scopes
3. Methods of your model

Check out this series of Blog articles on testing with RSpec, it should help:
http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an model spec (`describe User`) which does not allow to run requests, but you probably want to write a controller spec (`describe UsersController`) or even an integration test.

If you are using the default rspec layout, just move your code to the appropriate directory (`spec/controllers` or `spec/integration`). I would do an integration test:

```
# In spec/integration/user_registration_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User registration" do
  it "allows new users to register with an email address and password" do
    get "/users/sign_up"

    fill_in "Email",                 :with => "abc@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",              :with => "abc123"
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => "abc123"

    click_button "Sign up"

    response.body.should have_content("Welcome! You have signed up successfully.")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this file in the spec/models directory? I'm guessing that's the case since you're `describe`ing a `User`. The way you wrote your test is a mix between a controller-style test and an integration (acceptance) test. This is probably what you want:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  describe "user registration" do
    it "allows new users to register with an email address and password" do
      visit "/users/sign_up"

      fill_in "Email",                 :with => "abc@example.com"
      fill_in "Password",              :with => "abc123"
      fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => "abc123"

      click_button "Sign up"

      page.should have_content("Welcome! You have signed up successfully.")
    end
  end
end
```

Put this file in the spec/integration or spec/requests directory.

Comment: I don't have the spec/integration or spec/requests directory in my application. I want to test the devise authentication. As devise only generates model in the application on its own, so there's no Users Controller and that's why I have written this code in Models test.

Comment: just create the directory spec/requests and move this file into it.

Comment: You haven't migrated the database, then

Comment: As per your suggestion, I moved the file after creating the directory and now getting Failure/Error: get "/users/sign_up" ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users' – shah khan 7 mins ago

Comment: Did you also run `rake db:test:prepare` to get the schema into the test db?

Comment: do `visit /users/signup` not `get...`.

Comment: @DVG, No, I hadn't run rake db:test:prepare. Do I need to do so with rspec ?

Comment: Yes. Rspec runs against the test DB, so you need to run db:test:prepare anytime you change the development database

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try something like this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

describe "user registration" do
 it "allows new users to register with an email address and password" do
  visit new_user_registration_path
  current_path.should be(new_user_registration_path)

  fill_in "user[email]",                 :with => "abc@example.com"
  fill_in "user[password]",              :with => "abc123"
  fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", :with => "abc123"
  click_button "Sign up"

  expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  response.should be_redirect   
  response.should have_content("Welcome! You have signed up successfully.")
  end
 end
end
```

But I can highly recommend to using [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/) for generating new values. Also check, which Devise modules do you use. For example if you are using a Confirmable modul, is obvious that this approach is wrong. Some useful [article](http://garyrafferty.com/2011/09/29/Testing-devise-with-rspec-and-capybara.html).